How can i set alerts through bash based on dates?
I am writing a script that provides me dates with update times. I am trying to figure out how I can have the script let me know when something is past a certain time frame. For example if i have 100 workstations that have update date of May 1st but three of them have an update date of April 1st, i want it to be able to tell me that these 3 workstations are not up to date. It would be ideal if this script can somehow tell me when something hasn't been updated in 45 days or if there is an update date past 45 days.
I have tried seeing if i could somehow use if else statements for this.

If you provide the output that contains the update times of the 100 workstations then someone will surely be able to help you

Hy, I think this code will help you:
import datetime

workstations = {
    "workstation1": "2023-05-01",
    "workstation2": "2023-04-01",
    "workstation3": "2023-03-15",
    # add more [workstation_name lastupdate]
}
THRESHOLD_DAYS = 45

current_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

def parse_date(date_str):
    """Parse a date string into a datetime.date object."""
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

def is_up_to_date(update_date, threshold_days):
    """Check if the given update date is within the threshold days from the current date."""
    delta_days = (current_date - update_date).days
    return delta_days <= threshold_days

parsed_workstations = {ws: parse_date(date_str) for ws, date_str in workstations.items()}
outdated_workstations = [ws for ws, update_date in parsed_workstations.items() if not is_up_to_date(update_date, THRESHOLD_DAYS)]

for workstation in outdated_workstations:
    print(f"{workstation} is not up to date. Last update was on {workstations[workstation]}.")

print("\nWorkstation Status:")
for workstation, update_date in parsed_workstations.items():
    status = "Up to date" if is_up_to_date(update_date, THRESHOLD_DAYS) else "Outdated"
    print(f"{workstation}: {status} (Last update: {update_date})")

I use this code on my own vps and it's fine, except that my workstations are taken from the dynamic db

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
